# Understanding Rails URL parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Apologies for the basic question, however I am completely new to Rails and am trying to debug an existing application.

Specifically, I am trying to reverse-engineer the URL, given the following controller:

```
def find_by_foo
    params.require(:foo).permit(:bar1, :bar2)
end
```

The route is as follows:

```
get 'find_by_foo', on: :collection
```

And I even have a spec:

```
it "should not be successful" do
    get :find_by_foo, params: {foo: BarStuff}
    expect(response).to_not be_success
    expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
 end
```

I am trying to figure out how to pass these parameters via my REST client. I have tried the following URL structures:

```
api/v1/collections/find_by_foo?foo={bar1: 0, bar2: 0}
api/v1/collections/find_by_foo/foo/0/0
api/v1/collections/find_by_foo?params={foo: {bar1: 0, bar2: 0}}
```

All to now avail. What is the correct structure here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
api/v1/collections/find_by_foo?foo[bar1]=0&foo[bar2]=0
```

An overview of this is available in the [ActionController Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

You can also, in the console, call

```
app.find_by_foo_api_v1_collections_path(foo:{ bar1: 0, bar2: 0})
```

(or whatever the actual url helper method is, I'm just guessing based on the route), and you'll get the CGI-escaped version of the path that you can use. You can wrap that in `CGI.unescape(...)` for easier reading. E.g., in my app:

```
2.2.2 > CGI.unescape(app.edit_many_ops_media_files_path(foo:{ bar1: 0, bar2: 0}))
# => "/files/edit_many?foo[bar1]=0&foo[bar2]=0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print out the routes and filter by `find_by_foo` to see the correct structure. Run this in terminal:

```
$ rake routes | grep find_by_foo
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, however that does not tell me the parameter format. It just gives me: `/api/v1/foos/find_by_foo(.:format)      api/v1/foos#find_by_foo `

Comment: You can hit your API by visit this url: `localhost:3000/api/v1/foos/find_by_foo`, format could be .js, .html, .xml, .json depends on your implementation in `FoosController`'s `find_by_foo` method.

Comment: Thanks juanitofatas. It would be JSON.